# Finding isocontour lines, populating points on said lines (in MATLAB)

Tags: finite-element, matlab, numerical-modelling, mesh

I'm trying to extract data from a potential field. I have an example code of a potential field, using meshgrid in MATLAB. I've pasted the code below.

What I'd like to do next is 'convert' this field into a 2D graph, collect/graph the isocontours, and place data-points along the contour lines, ie. I want to collect a list of XY points along each contour (evenly spaced, probably) making the data easy to transfer or manipulate in other software etc.

ultimately without revealing too much about my research think I need to build up all the data points this way for multiple slices of 2D so that I have a densely populated 3D field of such points, eg. a constellation of spheres whose size depends on the potential of the isocontour it is on.

[image]

eg if this was my isoplot, I'd want dots/circles populated along the isocontour lines, with smaller tightly packed dots where there is the steeper gradient near the charges/obstacles, and larger dots in the periphery, filling up the space.

```
close all 
clear all
clc

xf = 0:0.1:12;
yf = 0:0.1:12;
[X Y] = meshgrid(xf,yf);

Goal=[10;10];
Obs1=[3;3];
Obs2=[9;9];
KG = 10;
Ko = 20;

rG = sqrt((Goal(1)-X).^2+(Goal(2)-Y).^2);
VG = KG*rG; %PF of Goal

ro1 = sqrt((Obs1(1)-X).^2+(Obs1(2)-Y).^2);
Vo1 = Ko./ro1; %PF of Obstacle 1

ro2 = sqrt((Obs2(1)-X).^2+(Obs2(2)-Y).^2);
Vo2 = Ko./ro2; %PF of Obstacle 2

figure
mesh(xf,yf,VG+Vo1+Vo2)
axis([0 12 0 12 0 200])
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
zlabel('V')

H4_PotentialNavigation

H4_PlatoonRobots

function [t,x]=H4_PotentialNavigation()

    clc

    time = [0 300];

    x0 = [0;0;0];

    Goal = [10;10];
    Obs1 = [3;3];
    Obs2 = [9;9];
    KG = 30;
    Ko = 30;

    [t x] = ode23(@vehicle,time,x0)
    figure
    plot(x(:,1),x(:,2),'r',Goal(1),Goal(2),'o',Obs1(1),Obs1(2),'x',Obs2(1),Obs2(2),'x')
    axis([0 12 0 12])

    function dx=vehicle(t,x)



        rG = sqrt((Goal(1)-x(1))^2+(Goal(2)-x(2))^2);
        FGx = KG*(Goal(1)-x(1))/rG;
        FGy = KG*(Goal(2)-x(2))/rG;

        ro1 = sqrt((Obs1(1)-x(1))^2+(Obs1(2)-x(2))^2);
        Fo1x = -Ko*(Obs1(1)-x(1))/ro1^3;
        Fo1y = -Ko*(Obs1(2)-x(2))/ro1^3;

        ro2 = sqrt((Obs2(1)-x(1))^2+(Obs2(2)-x(2))^2);
        Fo2x = -Ko*(Obs2(1)-x(1))/ro2^3;
        Fo2y = -Ko*(Obs2(2)-x(2))/ro2^3;

        Fx = (FGx+Fo1x+Fo2x);
        Fy = (FGy+Fo1y+Fo2y);

        alpha = atan(Fy/Fx);

        v = 1; 
        L = 2;

        if rG < 0.05 % Vehicle @ goal - stop
            v = 0;
        end

        K = 2;
        ph = K*(alpha-x(3));
        dx = [v*cos(ph)*cos(x(3));
              v*cos(ph)*sin(x(3));
              v*sin(ph)/L];
    end
end

function [t,x] = H4_PlatoonRobots()

clc

time = [0 300];
x0 = [0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0];

Goal = [10;10];
Obs1 = [3;3];
Obs2 = [9;9];
KG = 30;
Ko = 30;

[t x] = ode23(@vehicles,time,x0)
figure
plot (x(:,1),x(:,3),'b',x(:,5),x(:,7),'r',x(:,9),x(:,11),'g',...
    Goal(1),Goal(2),'o',Obs1(1),Obs1(2),'x',Obs2(1),Obs2(2),'x')
axis([0 12 0 12])

    function dx = vehicles(t,x)
        Goal = [10;10];
        Obs1=[3;3];
        Obs2=[9;9];
        KG=20;
        Ko=30;
        Kij=20;
        KLi=100;
        KF=10;
        rD=0.5; % Separation from Leader

        rG = sqrt((Goal(1)-x(1))^2+(Goal(2)-x(3))^2); % Leader and Goal
        FGx = KG*(Goal(1)-x(1))/max([rG 0.01]); % Division by Zero catch
        FGy = KG*(Goal(2)-x(3))/max([rG 0.01]);

        ro1 = sqrt((Obs1(1)-x(1))^2+(Obs1(2)-x(3))^2);
        Fo1x = -Ko*(Obs1(1)-x(1))/ro1^3;
        Fo1y = -Ko*(Obs1(2)-x(2))/ro1^3;

        ro2 = sqrt((Obs2(1)-x(1))^2+(Obs2(2)-x(3))^2);
        Fo2x = -Ko*(Obs2(1)-x(1))/ro2^3;
        Fo2y = -Ko*(Obs2(2)-x(2))/ro2^3;

        FrLx = -KF*x(2);
        FrLy = -KF*x(4);

        Fx = (FGx + Fo1x + Fo2x + FrLx);
        Fy = (FGy + Fo1y + Fo2y + FrLy);

        xL = [0 1; 0 0]*[x(1);x(2)]+[0;1]*Fx; % Leader Dynamics
        yL = [0 1; 0 0]*[x(3);x(4)]+[0;1]*Fy;

        r1o1 = sqrt((Obs1(1)-x(5))^2+(Obs1(2)-x(7))^2); % Follower 1 and Obs1
        F1o1x = -Ko*(Obs1(1)-x(5))/r1o1^3;
        F1o1y = -Ko*(Obs1(2)-x(7))/r1o1^3;

        r1o2 = sqrt((Obs2(1)-x(5))^2+(Obs2(2)-x(7))^2); % Follower 1 and Obs2
        F1o2x = -Ko*(Obs2(1)-x(5))/r1o2^3;
        F1o2y = -Ko*(Obs2(2)-x(7))/r1o2^3;

        rL1 = sqrt((x(1)-x(5))^2+(x(3)-x(7))^2); % Follower 1 and Leader
        FL1x = KLi *(rL1-rD)*(x(1)-x(5))/max([rL1 0.01]);
        FL1y = KLi *(rL1-rD)*(x(3)-x(7))/max([rL1 0.01]);

        r21 = sqrt((x(9)-x(5))^2+(x(11)-x(7))^2); % Follower 1 and Follower 2
        F21x = -2* Kij *(x(9)-x(5))/max([r21^4 0.01]);
        F21y = -2* Kij *(x(11)-x(7))/max([r21^4 0.01]);

        Fr1x = -KF*x(6);
        Fr1y = -KF*x(8);

        F1x = (F1o1x+F1o2x+FL1x+F21x+Fr1x);
        F1y = (F1o1y+F1o2y+FL1y+F21y+Fr1y);

        x1 = [0 1; 0 0]*[x(5);x(6)]+[0;1]*F1x; % Follower 1 Dynamics
        y1 = [0 1; 0 0]*[x(7);x(8)]+[0;1]*F1y;

        r2o1 = sqrt((Obs1(1)-x(9))^2+(Obs1(2)-x(11))^2); % Follower 2 and Obs1
        F2o1x = -Ko*(Obs1(1)-x(9))/r2o1^3;
        F2o1y = -Ko*(Obs1(2)-x(11))/r2o1^3;

        r2o2 = sqrt((Obs2(1)-x(9))^2+(Obs2(2)-x(11))^2); % Follower 2 and Obs2
        F2o2x = -Ko*(Obs2(1)-x(9))/r2o2^3;
        F2o2y = -Ko*(Obs2(2)-x(11))/r2o2^3;

        rL2 = sqrt((x(1)-x(9))^2+(x(3)-x(11))^2); % Follower 2 and Leader
        FL2x = KLi *(rL2-rD)*(x(1)-x(9))/max([rL2 0.01]);
        FL2y = KLi *(rL2-rD)*(x(3)-x(11))/max([rL2 0.01]);

        r12 = sqrt((x(5)-x(9))^2+(x(7)-x(11))^2); % Follower 2 and Follower 1
        F12x = -2* Kij *(x(5)-x(9))/max([r12^4 0.01]);
        F12y = -2* Kij *(x(7)-x(11))/max([r12^4 0.01]);

        Fr2x = -KF*x(10);
        Fr2y = -KF*x(12);

        F2x = (F2o1x+F2o2x+FL2x+F12x+Fr2x);
        F2y = (F2o1y+F2o2y+FL2y+F12y+Fr2y);

        x2 = [0 1; 0 0]*[x(9);x(10)]+[0;1]*F2x; % Follower 2 Dynamics
        y2 = [0 1; 0 0]*[x(11);x(12)]+[0;1]*F2y;

        dx = [xL(1);xL(2);yL(1);yL(2);x1(1);x1(2);y1(1);y1(2);x2(1);x2(2);...
            y2(1);y2(2)];

        if x(2) == 0 && x(4) == 0 % avoid local minima
            w = 0.001*randn(2,1);
            dx = dx + [0;w(1);0;w(2);0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0];
        end

        if r12 == 0 % Seperate followers from initial condition
            w = 0.001*randn(4,1);
            dx = dx + [0;0;0;0;0;w(1);0;w(2);0;w(3);0;w(4)];
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I think matlab’s contour and contourc have all the functionality you are looking for.